# Set ipy widget default value from list

Tags: python, list, iteration, ipywidgets

I have a list of values that I'd like to be my default values for some FloatBoxes I've dynamically created.

```
   list_of_inputs = df.columns.to_list()
   list_of_values = df.loc[0, :].values.tolist()

   floatboxes = [ipw.FloatText(value=________________,
               description=col,
               disabled=False,
               layout = {'width':'250px'}) for col in list_of_inputs]
```

This displays my floatboxes with the names taken from the column headers from my 1 row df. I just need the default value of the box to be the value thats in each column of the df.

I have tried

```
     ipw.FloatText(value=list_of_values[val] for val in list_of_values,
```

With no joy. Clearly a case of list iteration that I still havent go the hang of.

Answer (score 0):

So after spending more time messing around I found an answer. Not quite sure why it works so if someone wanted to explain what I'm missing that'd be amazing.

Answer :

```
list_of_inputs = df.columns.to_list()
list_of_values = df.loc[0, :].values.tolist()

floatboxes = [ipw.FloatText(value=df[col],
           description=col,
           disabled=False,
           layout = {'width':'250px'}) for col in df]
```

I ditched the lists and just referenced the original dataframe. It appears the df[col] gives me the value I needed.